# Should I use express.js framework or node.js http server?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, body-parser

I'm building a web-app where the event from html is translated as a query to the node js server. The node has to query the mongo and send back the response as json file.
My question is how can I write a json file from the result of the query? Should i use express framework to achieve this?

Comment: You don't have to. You can build Json from Node.js. Whether you should is an opinionated discussion, unsuitable for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Express for that but you don't have to. Express has a `res.json()` method for exactly that sort of thing but it's not the only framework that is good for that - other options include (but are not limited to) Hapi, Restify, LoopBack, Sails, Koa, Seneca, and few others.

If you decide to implement all of that yourself with the low level `http` module then keep one thing in mind: when you use `JSON.stringify()` to serialize your data to JSON you always need to put it in a try/catch block to handle exceptions that can happen for some input, or you can use the [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson) module.